# Can I use native compilation as Java obfuscation

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I am writing a plugin for a Java application. I could obfuscate the plugin, but it would still be easily reverse engineered.

I believe that if I could compile this plugin to a shared library, which heavily uses JNI to communicate with the main application, it would be much harder to reverse engineer. I am willing to sacrifice some performance to JNI, and the application I am coding against does support shared library loading. The only problem is that I am not aware of a tool which does the job: gcj seems to depend on its own runtime and IKVM.NET - on .NET

To be precise:

```
public class PluginImpl implements Plugin {
    @Override
    public void startPlugin(PluginContext ctx) {
       ctx.helloWorld();
    }  
}
```

should be converted to

```
public class PluginImpl implements Plugin {
    @Override
    public native void startPlugin(PluginContext ctx);
}
```

and the body of my startPlugin method is compiled into a shared library.

(well, yes, I know, I could have written this plugin in C in first place)

Comment: why do you say that obfuscated bytecode can be easily reverse engineered?

Comment: Anyone with the time and patience to de-obfuscate your bytecode can do the same with the native code, given more time. You're sacrificing performance, inability to debug, reliability (when the compiled-to-native Java invariably behaves differently compared to being run in the JVM) and days of your own time for very little "gain" and a vastly inferior product. **Give up now** while you haven't invested so much time in obfuscation that you feel you just *have* to ship the product like this...

Comment: Maybe you should port your app to Perl ;-)

Comment: I think if this approach were easy to automate and pull off, someone would have already turned it into a commercial obfuscation offering. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use *anything* for code obfuscation if you are distributing executable code in any form. Any executable code can be reverse engineered. This is a business problem not a technical problem, and it is solved by busniess means: licence agreements, price, time to market, or most probably a more realistic assessment of the risks and values, i.e. admitting to yourself that your code just isn't that valuable. Alternatively deliver your product as a service rather than as an executable.

Comment: Obfuscation is not meant to "prevent" reverse engineering, just to make it more difficult. As long as you are aware that if you distribute executable code it is actually impossible to completely prevent reverse engineering, there is nothing wrong with using obfuscation as a deterrent.

Comment: There is a definite cost and a possible benefit. It's a business decision.

Comment: You can say the same for any feature of any software product. Deciding whether the feature is implemented is a business decision. Design and implementation is a technical job. Likewise, deciding whether to use obfuscation is a business problem. Obfuscation itself is a technical topic.

Comment: @Grodriguez: obfuscation makes reverse engineering more time consuming - true {but not too much}, also provides good prayers for the relatives of the developers but in the end achieves nothing.

Comment: @bestsss: As most measures intended to protect against reverse engineering, "making the process more time consuming" is the key. Ideally, up to the point where it makes more sense to start from scratch than to try to reverse engineer the product.

Comment: @Grodriguez - I'm yet to see ANYTHING in java that took me more than 84 minutes to break. (as you might imagine 84 is the record). As I said already, you cant protect against heap dumps

Comment: @bestsss: Define "break". Unlike other protection measures, obfuscation does not need to be "broken" at all. The whole point of obfuscation is that _even if you had full access to the (obfuscated) source code_, you would still have a pretty hard time figuring out how it works.

Comment: @Grodriguez, that's 'break' part; there must a reason to prevent anyone understanding how it works. By 'break' I meant dropping any license alike defenses. My second language was assembler, compared to that Java cannot be considered obfuscate at any rate. There is no need to argue, obfuscation is an artificial but most of all useless way to defend against the unknown.

Comment: @bestsss: You are talking about "breaking licenses". This has nothing to do with my argument. I never said that obfuscation is useful to prevent copy protection. I said that it makes reverse engineering more difficult. Which it does.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have good reasons to go for native compilation. An option that you can examine is [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html) that is a Certified Java solution.

Comment: Still it runs its own runtime: "The resulting executables need the Excelsior JET Runtime to run, but not the Sun JRE." (http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jetfaq.html )

Comment: Well, +1 anyway for being a very interesting product.

Comment: Any Java app needs a Java runtime with garbage collector, context isolation (whether JNI, CNI, or something else), etc. Excelsior JET just precompiles the bytecode down to optimized native code. It still has a JIT compiler for handling classes that were not precompiled - dynamic proxies, third-party plugins, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your plugin provide its service over [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html). This way the plugin would be an application and could be compiled to native code.

Comment: Really good point, thank you. I suspect that out of process RMI would be too much of performance penalty, but I may give it a try. Added bonus is that I could use gcj then. I wish the API I am writing against was more serialization friendly.